# Hashcat syntax correction

Tags: hashcat

I've been cracking a box and I came across a password list and another file with the pass configuration. `$hash= md5($salt . pass . salt)` I have both salts and the password hash.

I tried with this syntax : `hashcat -m 3800 -a 0 '/path/to/pass/list' '/path/to/dictionary/list'` No devices found/left

It gives me nothing on return but an error saying there's not devices or anything. Im trying to get hashcat to crack these passwords. I've made a copy of my list and edited the list to have "User:salt:pass:salt". run it against rockyou.txt. What is my hashcat syntax missing specifically?

Comment: When asking for help with an error or a commend, always provide the actual output from the command instead of summarising. Copy/paste the test and use the code formatting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what type of machine you are using hashcat on and whether the hardware has OpenCL support, you should run `hashcat -I` which will tell you which OpenCL-supported devices are present on your machine. Hashcat can use CPU or GPU OpenCL resources.

You then specify which device(s) you want to use. [Hashcat Wiki](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat)

```
 -I, --opencl-info              |      | Show info about detected OpenCL platforms/devices    | -I
     --opencl-platforms         | Str  | OpenCL platforms to use, separated with commas       | --opencl-platforms=2
 -d, --opencl-devices           | Str  | OpenCL devices to use, separated with commas         | -d 1
 -D, --opencl-device-types      | Str  | OpenCL device-types to use, separated with commas    | -D 1
     --opencl-vector-width      | Num  | Manually override OpenCL vector-width to X           | --opencl-vector=4
```

Also if you are using any virtualization you may need to install OpenCL

Ex For Deb/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libhwloc-dev ocl-icd-dev ocl-icd-opencl-dev

apt-get install pocl-opencl-icd
```